# Carregar checkbox explode

Tags: php, html, array, mysqli, checkbox

Fiz um código com `explode` para carregar `checkbox` do `banco`, porém, ele só está carregando quando contém dados na exata ordem das variáveis, por exemplo 'Teatro 1, Teatro 2' carrega, mas 'Teatro 1, Baby Class' não carrega nenhum...

Embora eu tenha projetado para apenas duas opções fiz um teste com um `insert` de três, fora de ordem: 'Teatro 2, Teatro 1, Dança 1', carregou apenas o 'Dança 1'

```
 <?php $Oficina == $Oficina_Explode;
 $Oficina_Explode = explode(', ', $Oficina);
 $Oficina_Explode[0]; //ganha o valor 'Teatro 1'
$Oficina_Explode[1]; //ganha o valor 'Teatro 2
$Oficina_Explode[2]; //ganha o valor 'Dança 1'
$Oficina_Explode[3]; //ganha o valor 'Dança 2'
$Oficina_Explode[4]; //ganha o valor 'Baby Class'
?>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <label class="container">Teatro 1 <input class='shared' type='checkbox' value="Teatro 1" name="Oficina[]" required="required" <?php if($Oficina_Explode[0] == 'Teatro 1') echo 'checked';?> /><span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    <label class="container">Teatro 2 <input class='shared' type='checkbox' value="Teatro 2" name="Oficina[]" required="required" <?php if($Oficina_Explode[1] == 'Teatro 2') echo 'checked';?> /><span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    <label class="container">Dança 1 <input class='shared' type='checkbox' value="Dança 1" name="Oficina[]" required="required" <?php if($Oficina_Explode[2] ==   'Dança 1') echo 'checked';?> /><span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    <label class="container">Dança 2 <input class='shared' type='checkbox' value="Dança 2" name="Oficina[]" required="required" <?php if($Oficina_Explode[3] == 'Dança 2') echo 'checked';?> /><span class="checkmark"></span></label>
    <label class="container"> Baby Class<input class='shared' type='checkbox' value="Baby Class" name="Oficina[]" required="required" <?php if($Oficina_Explode[4] == 'Baby Class') echo 'checked';?> /><span class="checkmark"></span></label>
```

Como posso incrementar meu código para resolver este problema?

Comment: Confirmou se o valor armazenado no array é realmente a string que deseja?

Comment: Fiz os testes, acabo de ver que não se trata de acento... ele só está carregando quando contém dados na exata ordem das variáveis, por exemplo 'Teatro 1, Teatro 2' carrega, mas 'Teatro 1, Baby Class' não carrega nenhum...

Comment: Se vc deu a entrada com  'Teatro 2, Teatro 1, Dança 1', o que te garante que $Oficina_Explode[0] vai  ter o valor "Teatro 1", $Oficina_Explode[1] vai ter o valor "Teatro 2"? Imagino que esteja faltando informação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido. Obrigado aos comentários que me ajudaram a chegar na solução.

Criei um `if` para verificar cada `checkbox`, e assim, preenche-los corretamente.

```
    <?php $Oficina == $Oficina_Explode;
 $Oficina_Explode = explode(', ', $Oficina);
 $Oficina_Explode[0]; //ganha o valor 'Teatro 1'
$Oficina_Explode[1]; //ganha o valor 'Teatro 2
$Oficina_Explode[2]; //ganha o valor 'Dança 1'
$Oficina_Explode[3]; //ganha o valor 'Dança 2'
$Oficina_Explode[4]; //ganha o valor 'Baby Class'
if(in_array('Teatro 1', $Oficina_Explode)){
 echo "<label class='container'>Teatro 1 <input class='shared' type='checkbox' value='Teatro 1' name='Oficina[]' required='required' checked /><span class='checkmark'></span></label>";
}
else {
      echo "<label class='container'>Teatro 1 <input class='shared' type='checkbox' value='Teatro 1' name='Oficina[]' required='required' /><span class='checkmark'></span></label>";
}
if(in_array('Teatro 2', $Oficina_Explode)){
echo "<label class='container'>Teatro 2 <input class='shared' type='checkbox' value='Teatro 2' name='Oficina[]' required='required' checked /><span class='checkmark'></span></label>";
}
else{
      echo "<label class='container'>Teatro 2 <input class='shared' type='checkbox' value='Teatro 2' name='Oficina[]' required='required' /><span class='checkmark'></span></label>";
}
if(in_array('Dança 1', $Oficina_Explode)){
echo "<label class='container'>Dança 1 <input class='shared' type='checkbox' value='Dança 1' name='Oficina[]' required='required' checked /><span class='checkmark'></span></label>";
}
else
{
    echo "<label class='container'>Dança 1 <input class='shared' type='checkbox' value='Dança 1' name='Oficina[]' required='required' /><span class='checkmark'></span></label>";  
}
if(in_array('Dança 2', $Oficina_Explode)){
echo "<label class='container'>Dança 2 <input class='shared' type='checkbox' value='Dança 2' name='Oficina[]' required='required' checked /><span class='checkmark'></span></label>";
}
else{
      echo "<label class='container'>Dança 2 <input class='shared' type='checkbox' value='Dança 2' name='Oficina[]' required='required' /><span class='checkmark'></span></label>";
}
if(in_array('Baby Class', $Oficina_Explode)){
echo "<label class='container'> Baby Class<input class='shared' type='checkbox' value='Baby Class' name='Oficina[]' required='required' checked /><span class='checkmark'></span></label>";
}
else{
      echo "<label class='container'> Baby Class<input class='shared' type='checkbox' value='Baby Class' name='Oficina[]' required='required' /><span class='checkmark'></span></label>";
}
?>
```